# NodeJS + MQTT - Publshing at 1ms frequency causes EventEmitter memory leak

Tags: node.js, mqtt, load-testing, publish-subscribe, eventemitter

I want to simulate high volume of messages and so I used this in my `index.js`. I am using [`mqtt`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt) module.

```js
var client = mqtt.connect('mqtts://broker.com:8883', {
  ca: [fs.readFileSync('broker.pem')],
  rejectUnauthorized: false
})

let frequency = process.env.FREQUENCY || 1000
client.on('connect', function () {
  let count = 0
  setInterval(() => {
    process.stdout.clearLine()
    process.stdout.cursorTo(0)
    client.publish('/topic/string', JSON.stringify(getPayload()), (err) => {
      if (err) {

      } else {
        ++count
        process.stdout.write('Messages published :' + count)
      }
    })
  }, frequency)
})
```

When I run it as `export FREQUENCY=1 && node index.js`, I get this error.

```sh
nsubrahm@nsubrahm simulator % node index.js     
(node:2313) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 1001 drain listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 1001 drain listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
    at _addListener (events.js:243:17)
    at TLSSocket.addListener (events.js:259:10)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.on (_stream_readable.js:799:35)
    at TLSSocket.once (events.js:290:8)
    at sendPacket (/my/simulator/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:99:19)
    at MqttClient._sendPacket (/my/simulator/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:1061:7)
    at MqttClient.publish (/my/simulator/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:541:14)
    at Timeout.setInterval [as _onTimeout] (/my/simulator/index.js:53:12)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
```

I even tried running 5 instances of `index.js` with frequency of 5 seconds each; so that overall, I can see load of close to per 1 ms behavior. Same error.

How do I simulate a client that does MQTT publish at 1ms frequency?

Comment: 1 ms is a very short amount to time to get through both a client.publish() and a JSON.stringify() function call.  If the function assigned to your setInterval() call takes longer than 1 ms, then it pretty much guarantees you will eventually run out of memory on your computer, no matter how big it is.

Comment: If you are looking to load test an MQTT application, you might want to try something like MQTTbox (https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-toolbox-mqttbox/)

Comment: I was unable to set-up TLS in MQTTBox for load testing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the code is not the problem, even setting the frequency variable with 1 it worked for me because I can see the message in the console without warnings, maybe other part of the code like getPayload() is creating a lot of listeners and that could cause the warning.

Try to limit the listeners that can be create with the client variable and set a simple text in the `client.publish('/topic/string', JSON.stringify(getPayload()),` like this:

```js
...
var client = mqtt.connect('mqtts://broker.com:8883', {
  ca: [fs.readFileSync('broker.pem')],
  rejectUnauthorized: false
})
/** This will avoid the MaxListenerExceededWarning */
client.setMaxListeners(100)
...

...
// Do not use JSON.stringify(getPayLoad())
client.publish('/topic/string', 'JUST_TYPE_THIS', (err) => { ...
...
```

This problem is explained [here](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_setmaxlisteners_n)

**Update**

Snippet code avoiding memory leak warning

```js
var mqtt = require('mqtt')
// Changed URL
var client  = mqtt.connect('mqtt://test.mosquitto.org')

// IMPORTANT: Limit listeners
client.setMaxListeners(100)

// Changed ms to 1 ms for this example
//let frequency = process.env.FREQUENCY || 1000
let frequency = 1

client.on('connect', function () {
  let count = 0
  setInterval(() => {
    process.stdout.clearLine()
    process.stdout.cursorTo(0)
    // Set harcoded key-value but you need to set
    // real key-value
    client.publish('/topic/string', 'key-value-example', (err) => {
      if (err) {

      } else {
        ++count
        process.stdout.write('Messages published :' + count)
      }
    })
  }, frequency)
})
```

Comment: I can't avoid `JSON.stringify(getPayLoad())` because that is the core of the simulator. Nevertheless, the `getPayload` is just a collection of 3 calls `Math.Random()` to build a JSON object with 3 key-value pairs.

Comment: Are you saying, this is not an issue with the callback? I can't avoid the callback too because, I need to keep a track of how many publications happened and therefore how many subscribed, etc.

Comment: I understand, you can just try to use one of your key-value simulator (hardcode) just for testing, and yes this is not a issue with the callback,  this issue is due that in some part of your code is trying to set a lot of listeners and Node Js is warning you that could cause memory leak.

Comment: Well, removal of callback does not cause the event emitter issue.

Comment: I'll do an update with the code that it worked for me, if you use it, the warning won't appear.

Comment: Without the `getPayload()` function, the code snippet doesn't help.

Comment: With the hard-coded key-value and `client.setMaxListeners(100)` too, the same error happens.

Comment: Try to create a new file like index.js and run the update code and run only this new file with `node index.js`